# Efficiently computing $e^{tX}$ for many different values of $t$

Tags: linear-algebra, python, matrix, sparse-matrix

Given an anti-Hermitian and sparse matrix $X$, I am using Python (NumPy and SciPy) to compute the matrix exponential $f(t) := e^{tX}$ for  many values of $t$. The method I am currently using is to essentially compute the exponent with the following function:

```
X = SomeSparseMatrix
def f(t):
    return scipy.sparse.linalg.expm(t * X)
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to make this faster. For example, if I compute this function once to obtain $e^X$, can I obtain $e^{tX}$ from $e^X$ without having to recompute the exponent?

Comment: Does your matrix have any useful properties? The link below provides some ideas for solving your problem. Even powers of antihermitian matrices are hermitian, and odd powers are antihermitian. Perhaps you can do something with that?

https://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/linear-algebra/matrix-exponential/matrix-exponential.html

Comment: If $t$ is an integer, you should be able to compute $e^{tX}$ using repeated squaring. Since $e^X$ is unitary, the terms of the matrix won't blow up

Comment: Have you searched for the two papers about "dubious ways to compute the matrix exponential"?

Comment: This is the paper that @WolfgangBangerth is referring to and I also highly recommend it: https://doi.org/10.1137/S00361445024180

Comment: Another question -- do you actually need the matrix exponential itself, or do you only need its action $e^{tX}\cdot v$ for some vector $v$? In many applications it's the latter and there are better ways to do that without explicitly computing the exponential. In general the exponential of a sparse matrix is dense, just like the inverse. If you can avoid explicitly forming this matrix then you should do so.

Comment: Incidentally, I have looked at that scipy code, and what they do seems quite dubious, in my view. If I am not mistaken, they use a Padé approximation $Q(X)^{-1}P(X)$ without scaling and squaring, forming explicitly the dense(-ish) matrix polynomial $Q(X)$, and then factorizing it. It looks like even just using partial fractions would get something more efficient, and Padé approximations for matrices with large eigenvalues rate to be completely off.

Comment: Could you expand on the range of values of $t$ that you need? Are they very close? Are they real? How large are they wrt the eigenvalues of $X$? Are they multiples of a certain value, as suggested by ogogmad, or equispaced?

Comment: The answer to this question was sufficient for my needs, but maybe for posterity - I am essentially trying to minimize a function $\langle v, O(t)v\rangle$, where $O(t) = \prod_i \text{exp}(tX_i)$, and $t\in\mathbb{R}$. As a result, diagonalizing each $X_i$ and acting $P_ie^{tD_i}P_i^{-1}$ sped it up quite significantly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An anti-Hermitian matrix is diagonalizable, with orthogonal eigenvectors ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-Hermitian_matrix)). Hence you can write $X = PDP^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Therefore the exponential can be calculated as $e^X=Pe^DP^{-1}$, and $e^{tX} = Pe^{tD}P^{-1}$.

If $d_1$, $d_2$, etc.... are the diagonal elements of $D$, then for each value of $t_i \in t$, $e^{t_iD}$ is just a diagonal matrix with elements $e^{t_id_1}$, $e^{t_id_2}$, etc....Now your calculation of the exponential for each value $t_i$ is just reduced to $N$ scalar exponentiations for an $N\times N$ matrix $X$.

You still have the task of diagonalizing $X$,but you only have to do it once. If $t$ has $M$ elements, then you also have $2M$ matrix multiplications to do.

So you would be trading $M$ matrix exponentiations for one diagonalization of $X$, as well as $N\cdot M$ scalar exponentiations, and $2M$ matrix multiplications. I don't know what the complexity of matrix exponentiation is, but I think this is likely to be a good trade.

As Daniel Shapero points out in his comment above, if you only need the action of $e^{tX}v$ for some vector $v$ and don't really need the matrix, then you can often save a whole lot of time. That savings is easy to realize with this approach, since $e^{tX}v = Pe^{tD}P^{-1}v=Pe^{tD}(P^{-1}v)$. You only do the $P^{-1}v$ calculation once, and the $Pe^{tD}$ calculations can be done faster than an ordinary matrix multiplication since $e^{t_iD}$ is a diagonal matrix. In this case, the diagonalization is the only thing that scales as $N^3$ (or maybe a bit less, depending on the implementation of the diagonalization), and it is done just once, not once per each point in $t$.